# How do I insert 2 spaces every 2 characters in a string?

Tags: sql, string, db2-400

i have a table with a 250 char column, with a content like:

```
AA1BB1CC1DD1
AA1DD1EE1
AA1XX1EE2FF1AB2CB2
```

it's a string used like an array of 2char + 1 char. I need to insert 2 spaces after the first 2 of each array's element:

```
AA  1BB  1CC  1DD  1
AA  1DD  1EE  1
AA  1XX  1EE  2FF  1AB  2CB  2
```

is there a system function (maybe regexp_replace?) or i need write a program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with REGEXP_REPLACE (tested with DB2 for IBM i 7.3)

```
with table1 (c1) as (
  values
  'AA1BB1CC1DD1',
  'AA1DD1EE1',
  'AA1XX1EE2FF1AB2CB2',
  'AA1A51B11'
)
select c1, regexp_replace(c1, '(\w{2})(\d)', '\1  \2') modified
from table1
```

| C1 | MODIFIED |
| --- | --- |
| AA1BB1CC1DD1 | AA 1BB 1CC 1DD 1 |
| AA1DD1EE1 | AA 1DD 1EE 1 |
| AA1XX1EE2FF1AB2CB2 | AA 1XX 1EE 2FF 1AB 2CB 2 |
| AA1A51B11 | AA 1A5 1B1 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/fWr1FYMD)

Answer (score 0):

Add two spaces before any number in Python using RegEx:

```
import re  
modified_text = re.sub(r'(\d)', r'  \1', text)
```

Comment: i forgot that the 2 chars are alphanumeric, so i could also have:

AA1A51B11

which should become:

AA 1A5 1B1 1